# insert xml string to xml element using LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml, xelement

i want combine two xml that one of them is template and other is data, how can i do this?

XML one:

```
<magazine>
  <content>
    <page no="1"></page>
    <page no="2"></page>
    <page no="3"></page>
  </content>
</magazine>
```

XML two:

```
<data>
  <page no="1">data1</Page>
  <page no="2">data2</Page>
  <page no="3">data3</Page>
</data>
```

Comment: I want to see what you have tried and what is your expected results. How can I do this?

Comment: Use XSLT. This article can help you

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms766462%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: can you please show your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linq solution:

```
var content = XDocument.Load("content.xml")
                       .Root.Elements("page")
                       .ToDictionary(p => (int)p.Attribute("no"));

var xdoc = XDocument.Load("template.xml");

foreach (var page in xdoc.Descendants("page"))
{
    XElement data;
    if (!content.TryGetValue((int)page.Attribute("no"), out data))
        continue;

    page.ReplaceNodes(data.Nodes());
}
```

Comment: tanx for reply, but i forgot say that my data is xml and i want insert xml into xml element

Comment: @mahdiyousefi no problem - you should replace nodes of page with nodes of page content. Updated solution